# Command binding to a button inside a DataTemplate not working

Tags: wpf, button, command, datatemplate

Example:

```
<ListBox Name="List" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
             SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel >
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Show" Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Clicking the button does nothing. I tried to bind the command to a button outside the `DataTemplate` and it works. I also tried to register the button in the `DataTemplate` to a `Click_event` and this did work.

Why is the command not working inside the DataTemplate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the Command is defined in the `ListBox`'s `DataContext`, Use either a `RelativeSource` Binding to help the `Button` locate the Command:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel >
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Show" Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or use an `ElementName` binding:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel >
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Show" Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowCommand,ElementName=List}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```